# Error with expo-modules-core when running pod install

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, podfile

The error is:

[!] No podspec found for "" in
node_modules/expo-modules-core/
ios

I am using sdk 41. I cannot update the sdk of the project because it is required.

My Podfile looks like this:

```
  require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
    require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'
    require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
    
    platform :ios, '11.0'
    
    target 'myProject' do
    use_unimodules!
    config = use_native_modules!
    
    use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])
    
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable these next few lines.
    use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.87.0', 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1'})
    post_integrate do |installer|
    begin
    expo_patch_react_imports!(installer)
    rescue => e
      Pod::UI.warn e
    end
   end
 end
```

I have tried to reinstall node modules, delete Pods folder and reinstall them again. Nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

you need to run npx install-expo-modules@latest to fix this issue.
This problem occurred because expo modules is not installed

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem by forcing to use modular headers in Podfile. Add following line right after `prepare_react_native_project!`:

> **`use_frameworks! :linkage => :static`**

Then running `npx pod-install` inside ios folder has installed everything.